# how to change taxonomy term fields before being created first time

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to copy parent's image field to a "goint to be created" taxonomy term using this code but it isn't working:

```
function my_module_taxonomy_term_insert($term) {
    if ($term->vid == 29) {

        //if any of parents have logo then copy it
            foreach ($term->parent as $p) {

            if (isset($p->field_image[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['fid'])) {
                //copy the image
                $filepath = drupal_realpath($p->field_image[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['uri']);

                // Create managed File object and associate with Image field.
                $file = (object) array(
                            'uid' => 1,
                            'uri' => $filepath,
                            'filemime' => file_get_mimetype($filepath),
                            'status' => 1,
                );

                $term->field_image[LANGUAGE_NONE][0] = (array) $file;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to do this?

Comment: you need to call `taxonomy_term_save` function to save changes..

Comment: I guess Drupal core will call this after all hooks are run since it's very new term getting created

Comment: but you are getting a full `$term` object as argument, this means that object's been created already.. May be  I am wrong.. But docs say a little bit defferent..

Comment: why you want it before saving the term, i do not think you can get terms parent before its actually even created,it might be asking for something which does not exist in the system.

Comment: Are you sure this is the best approach? If you only need it for display, solve it in the theme layer: if there is no image for current term, display parent term image.

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal 7, you can achieve this by using the following taxonomy APIs

- **[hook_taxonomy_term_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.api.php/function/hook_taxonomy_term_insert/7)** : Act on taxonomy terms when inserted.
- **[taxonomy_term_load](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_load/7)** : To load the taxonomy by using term ID
- **[taxonomy_term_save](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_save/7)** : To update the taxonomy by using term ID

```
/**
 * Implementing hook_taxonomy_term_insert
 */
function hook_taxonomy_term_insert($term) {
  $vid = 2; //User your vid
  if (is_object($term) && $term->vid == $vid && isset($term->parent)) {
    //get parent tid using $term->parent array
    foreach ($term->parent as $ptid) {//check image for each parent, if image exist assign and exit
      if ($ptid > 0) {//except root
        //get parent image WHERE field_data_field_image_vocab_image is the parent image field
        $pfid = db_select('field_data_field_image_vocab_image', 'pimg')//change field_data_field_image_vocab_image with your field name
            ->condition('pimg.entity_id', $ptid, '=')
            ->fields('pimg', array('field_image_vocab_image_fid'))//change field_image_vocab_image_fid with your image fid name
            ->execute()->fetchField();
        $update_taxo = taxonomy_term_load($term->tid); //load created taxonomy
        if ($pfid > 0 && empty($update_taxo->field_image_vocab_image)) {//image exist for this parent $ptid and image is not assigned yet
          $update_taxo->field_image_vocab_image[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['fid'] = $pfid;
          taxonomy_term_save($update_taxo); //update taxonomy after assigning image
          break; //break after saving the image
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note :

- Change the field names
- Go through the comments for explanation.

Comment: Here is the same code, using `entity_metadata_wrappers` https://gist.github.com/barraponto/06413bbd518c87410aa1

Answer (score 0):

I doubt in `$parents = taxonomy_get_parents($term->tid);`since this is presave hook, so you might not be getting the term id. Presave hooks are suppose to call before the taxonomy is actually created so might be no tid, so instead of persave you can go for [hook_taxonomy_term_insert()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.api.php/function/hook_taxonomy_term_insert/7),this hook get invoked after term is created.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own submit handler and change term properties while it's not saved.

You can add your custom form submit handler before term_insert.
Look at hook_form_alter and add your custom submit function before taxonomy_form_term_submit.